# How to change text alignment of a combo box items in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a Combo Box in my app . I added some items as string to it . Items have left alignment . I want the right alignment . I searched a lot but i cant find anything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the following solution, although I'm not sure if it's a good one:

[image]

---

For button cell:

```
box.setButtonCell(new ListCell<String>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null) {
            setText(item);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            Insets old = getPadding();
            setPadding(new Insets(old.getTop(), 0, old.getBottom(), 0));
        }
    }
});
```

For popup list view:

```
box.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
        return new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    setText(item);
                    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                    setPadding(new Insets(3, 3, 3, 0));
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```